# Join acting strange print all inputs instead from only user 1

Tags: mysql, join

Hey there I tough you guys that seems to have the expertise up,
I'd most say i have no clue about these join concepts after even read up on it.

```
$resource = $DBcon->query('SELECT* FROM dogs JOIN rapport  AS `FULL JOIN` WHERE  user_id="2"');
```

Don't know if this is slightly right I've used a online generator.

```
  while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
  //  echo "<pre>";
    //  echo print_r($row);
    //  echo "</pre>";
    echo $row['activity1']."<br>";
}
```

My setup is in dogs.table `id` then in rapport.table I have `user_id`

I've setup two users in rapport `user_id['1']` & `user_id['2']` 

when i try print all data from `user_id=2` it prints in the loop every user in `dogs.table` with the activity.

```
    user 2 eat
    user 2 sleep
    user 2 eat
    user 2 sleep
    user 2 eat
    user 2 sleep
    user 2 eat
    user 2 sleep
    user 2 eat
    user 2 sleep
```

What it should have outputted is just the first 2 rows but how ?

Comment: You can consider to use a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changed when i used `GROUP BY` think it's the querry that's the oddball in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resource = $DBcon->query('SELECT * FROM dogs JOIN rapport ON dogs.id = rapport.id  where rapport.id="1"  ');
```

After some tinkering with the code this solved it, and I may finally got a grasp how it works.